# Не получается корректно пройти массив через setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, циклы, setinterval, dataset

```
Код HTML
<main class="content">
    <div class="card">
        <p>
            Цифры
            <span class="rotator">
            <span class="rotator__case rotator__case_active" data-speed="1000" data-color="red">11111</span>
            <span class="rotator__case" data-speed="2000" data-color="green">22222</span>
            <span class="rotator__case" data-speed="1000" data-color="#000">33333</span>
            <span class="rotator__case" data-speed="1000" data-color="red">44444</span>
            <span class="rotator__case" data-speed="500" data-color="blue">55555</span>
            <span class="rotator__case" data-speed="200" data-color="gray">66666</span>
          </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</main>

Код JS

let now = new Date();

    /* МАССИВ СПАНОВ */

let arrRotator = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.rotator__case'));

    /* МАССИВ СКОРОСТИ */

let arr = arrRotator.map(elem => elem = elem.getAttribute('data-speed'));
console.log(arr);

    /* ОСНОВНАЯ ПРОГРАММА */

let mainProgram = () => {
  let activeRotator = document.querySelector('.rotator__case_active'); // Класс выводящий надпись на экран
  activeRotator.closest('span').style.color = activeRotator.closest('span').dataset.color; // Задаю цвет из dataset

  let now1 = new Date(); // Считается время
  console.log(now1 - now); // (проверка на правильный счётчик)

  if (arrRotator[arrRotator.length - 1].className != 'rotator__case rotator__case_active') { 
    activeRotator.nextElementSibling.className = 'rotator__case rotator__case_active'; // Следующий за активным элемент активируется
    activeRotator.className = 'rotator__case'; // Активный элемент деактивируется
  }
  else {
    activeRotator.className = 'rotator__case'; // Если последний элемент
    arrRotator[0].className = 'rotator__case rotator__case_active'; // Он становится первым
  }
}

    /* ЦИКЛ С ИНТЕРВАЛОМ */

arr.forEach(time => {
  setInterval(mainProgram, time * 5);
});
```

Суть вопроса в следующем:

1. Я хочу задать время для интервала через data-speed. Для этого я создал массив скоростей, добавил setInterval в цикл forEach, и назначил элемент массива "временем интервала". В результате, когда программа проходит все значения span, происходит однократное моментальное выполнение всех спан сразу, из за чего сбивается таймер.
2. Я также добавил цвет каждому активному спану. Но цвет присваивается только со 2го круга прохода элементов (не важно с циклом или без). Почему так?
3. Когда вставляю время из массива в setInterval, их нужно умножать на 5 для получения установленного времени в элементе массива. Почему время в мс не устанавливается сразу?

Помогите разобраться с этими задачами.

Comment: Как минимум `elem.getAttribute('data-speed')` тут вы получаете строку. Преобразуйте в число

Comment: И еще момент - когда вы корректно запустите все ваш **setInterval**, то они будут работать параллельно и не зависимо друг от друга, а не последовательно. Какого именно поведения вы хотите достичь данным кодом?

Comment: Я хочу чтобы спаны по-очереди появлялись на экране, т.е.: один активен, остальные скрыты.

Comment: Можно поподробнее, что значит "они будут работать параллельно и не зависимо друг от друга"?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arrRotator = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.rotator__case'));

let arr = arrRotator.map(elem => parseInt(elem.getAttribute('data-speed')));

let currentIndex = 0;

function runRotator() {
  let activeRotator = document.querySelector('.rotator__case_active');
  if (activeRotator) {
    activeRotator.closest('span').style.color = activeRotator.closest('span').dataset.color;

    let nextRotator = activeRotator.nextElementSibling || arrRotator[0]; // Если нет следующего элемента, возьмем первый элемент
    nextRotator.className = 'rotator__case rotator__case_active';
    activeRotator.className = 'rotator__case';

    currentIndex = arrRotator.indexOf(nextRotator);
    setTimeout(runRotator, arr[currentIndex]);
  }
}

setTimeout(runRotator, arr[0]);
```

```html
<main class="content">
        <div class="card">
            <p>

                <span class="rotator">
                    <span class="rotator__case rotator__case_active" data-speed="1000" data-color="red">11111</span>
                    <span class="rotator__case" data-speed="2000" data-color="green">22222</span>
                    <span class="rotator__case" data-speed="1000" data-color="#000">33333</span>
                    <span class="rotator__case" data-speed="1000" data-color="red">44444</span>
                    <span class="rotator__case" data-speed="500" data-color="blue">55555</span>
                    <span class="rotator__case" data-speed="200" data-color="gray">66666</span>
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Этот код обновляет цвет активного span и запускает циклическое изменение активных элементов с учетом заданных скоростей data-speed

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Протестировал, таймер работает хорошо. Но с цветами беда, они снова со 2го круга приписываются

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrRotator = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.rotator__case'));

let arr = arrRotator.map(elem => parseInt(elem.getAttribute('data-speed')));

// Устанавливаем начальный цвет активного элемента
let activeRotator = document.querySelector('.rotator__case_active');
if (activeRotator) {
activeRotator.closest('span').style.color = activeRotator.closest('span').dataset.color;
}

let currentIndex = 0;

function runRotator() {
let activeRotator = document.querySelector('.rotator__case_active');
if (activeRotator) {
    let nextRotator = activeRotator.nextElementSibling || arrRotator[0];
    nextRotator.closest('span').style.color = nextRotator.closest('span').dataset.color;
    nextRotator.className = 'rotator__case rotator__case_active';
    activeRotator.className = 'rotator__case';

    currentIndex = arrRotator.indexOf(nextRotator);
    setTimeout(runRotator, arr[currentIndex]);
}
}

setTimeout(runRotator, arr[0]);
```

Теперь цвет активного элемента должен устанавливаться с первого круга.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Пожалуйста! Рад, что смог Вам помочь в решении этой задачи! )))

Comment: Не плодите почти одинаковые ответы под одним и тем же вопросом. Если желаете улучшить ответ, используйте кнопку [edit] и редактируйте, не занимайтесь копированием.

Comment: Благодарю за рекомендации, спасибо за внимание! ))